# Получение записи по её номеру из DataTable

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Имеется таблица, в которую записываются значения сигнала GSM-сети.

Структура и данные таблицы:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM signallvl;
+---------+----------------+------+------------+----------+
| id_post | name           | LVL  | day        | time     |
+---------+----------------+------+------------+----------+
|       1 | Uroven signala |    1 | 2015-09-18 | 09:50:54 |
|       2 | Uroven signala |    1 | 2015-09-18 | 09:50:54 |
|       3 | Uroven signala |    1 | 2015-09-18 | 09:51:15 |
|       4 | Uroven signala |    1 | 2015-09-18 | 09:51:15 |
|       5 | Uroven signala |    1 | 2015-09-18 | 09:52:52 |
|       6 | Uroven signala |    1 | 2015-09-18 | 09:53:00 |
|       7 | Uroven signala |   87 | 2015-09-18 | 09:59:52 |
|       8 | Uroven signala |   93 | 2015-09-18 | 10:00:48 |
|       9 | Uroven signala |   90 | 2015-09-18 | 10:15:05 |
|      10 | Uroven signala |   93 | 2015-09-18 | 10:22:05 |
|      11 | Uroven signala |   93 | 2015-09-18 | 10:31:55 |
|      12 | Uroven signala |   90 | 2015-09-18 | 10:43:05 |
|      13 | Uroven signala |   93 | 2015-09-18 | 10:51:05 |
|      14 | Uroven signala |   90 | 2015-09-18 | 10:52:05 |
|      15 | Uroven signala |   93 | 2015-09-18 | 11:05:06 |
|      16 | Uroven signala |   87 | 2015-09-18 | 11:06:07 |
|      17 | Uroven signala |   90 | 2015-09-18 | 11:12:06 |
|      18 | Uroven signala |   87 | 2015-09-18 | 11:13:09 |
|      19 | Uroven signala |   90 | 2015-09-18 | 11:19:05 |
|      20 | Uroven signala |   93 | 2015-09-18 | 11:20:04 |
|      21 | Uroven signala |   90 | 2015-09-18 | 11:27:08 |
|      22 | Uroven signala |   93 | 2015-09-18 | 11:34:04 |
|      23 | Uroven signala |   90 | 2015-09-18 | 11:35:07 |
|      24 | Uroven signala |   83 | 2015-09-18 | 11:42:04 |
|      25 | Uroven signala |   87 | 2015-09-18 | 11:43:10 |
|      26 | Uroven signala |   87 | 2015-09-18 | 11:50:15 |
+---------+----------------+------+------------+----------+
26 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Код, с помощью которого я получаю значения, следующий:

```
DateTimePicker dateTimePicker1 = new DateTimePicker();
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today;
string connect = "Server=<адрес сервера>" + "Database=<Имя БД>;" + "Uid=<Логин>;" +
"Pwd=<Пароль>;" + "CharSet = cp1251; ";
MySqlConnection SQLConnect = new MySqlConnection(connect);
MySqlCommand SQLCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `signallvl`", SQLConnect);
try
{
    SQLConnect.Open();
    SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MySqlDataAdapter MyData = new MySqlDataAdapter(SQLCommand);
    DataTable Table = new DataTable();
    MyData.Fill(Table);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
     SQLConnect.Close();
}
```

Полученные данные хранятся `Table`. Как мне обратиться к этой таблице, чтобы узнать уровень сигнала, например, в 8-й записи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых, table позволяет просто обращатся к строкам по индексу. Если вам нужна просто 8-я строка, а не строка с id = 8, то достаточно написать:

```
DataRow row = table.Rows[7]; // индексация от 0
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", row["id_post"], row["name"], row["LVL"]);
```

`row["id_post"]`, `row["name"]` возвращают object. если вам нужна строгая типизация - сделайте `using System.Linq` и используйте методы расширения вида:

```
string name = row.Field<string>("name");
```

Если нужна именно строка с id = 8, то вместо тупого for можно использовать `DataView`. Он позволяет писать базовые запросы поверх `DataTable`:

```
var view = new DataView(table);
view.RowFilter = "id_post = 8";
DataRowView rowView = view[0];
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", rowView["id_post"], rowView["name"], rowView["LVL"]);
```

Или вы можете использовать Linq, преобразовать DataRows в нормальные объекты, и выбрать данные через `Where` или `Single`:

```
var rowData = table.AsEnumerable().Select(r =>
    new
    {
        id_post = r.Field<int>("id_post"),
        name = r.Field<string>("name")
    }).Single(r => r.id_post == 8);

Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", rowData.id_post, rowData.name);
```

В любом случае, не стоит использовать DataTable или DataAdapter в новых приложениях. Это древний способ для ручной работы с данными - хоть он и упоминается во всех книгах по C#. Сейчас его более чем заменили ORM. Вам стоит посмотреть в сторону Entity Framework. Для него есть [родной коннектор к EF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Entity/) и достаточно [простые примеры по использованию](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите ответ в этом [вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1346142/2082873), тут предлагается использовать foreach, но как вариант можно и простой цикл for

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.